# Drag and Drop of Special Shell Objects To WPF

Tags: wpf, shell, drag-and-drop

I'm implementing a drag and drop operation, which works perfectly fine for files, folders, links, URIs, etc.  The only thing left is windows special shortcuts, such as the "Programs and Features" control panel item.  Those shortcuts seem to execute windows within the shell, as opposed to links or msc files.  How can I store this type of drop data and launch the item referenced at a later time? (i.e. bookmark it within my WPF app) I guess what I'm really asking is, how do I interpret the drop data?

Answer (score 0):

To figure this out, I had to read about how the shell namespace works (didn't really know is was called "namespace" until I found this article):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144090(v=vs.85).aspx

As well, this code helped understand it better:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3551/C-does-Shell-Part-1

This site helped to find the correct dll import code for .net:
http://www.pinvoke.net/